# Which is considered better to get the individual digits of a number? Divide-modulus or string charAt?

Tags: java, string, optimization, numbers

**Approach 1:**

Repeated `Division-modulus` operations.

```
long num = 123456789;
int count = 0;
while(num > 0)
{
 int digit = num % 10;
 if(digit == 1)
  count ++;
 num /= 10;
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Convert it into an `String` and get the characters at the position.

```
long num = 123456789;
int count = 0;
String s = String.valueOf(num);
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
 char ch = s.charAt(i);
 if(ch == '1')
    count ++;
}
```

The second operation doesn't need to get the remainder and the quotient each time. A `charAt()` method can be enough.

Which approach is considered to be better and why?

**EDIT**
Consider taking the input from the console.

```
1st Case: 
long num = scanner.nextLong();

2nd Case:
String s = scanner.nextLine();
```

Here there would be no overhead on converting the `number` to `string`.

Also let us assume it is for positive numbers.

Comment: Why are you creating a `StringBuffer` in the second case? (And why are you perform string concatenation?) Just use `String text = String.valueOf(num);`

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For better and details answer consider posting it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, I'd say it's reasonable to use a string representation. After all, the count you're finding is less inherently about its numeric value than its decimal string representation - you'd get a different value if you converted it into hex instead.

For operations which are more base-neutral, I'd normally avoid performing a string conversion.

Note that you don't need a `StringBuffer` for your second approach. I'd use:

```
long num = 123456789;
int count = 0;
String text = String.valueOf(num);
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char ch = text.charAt(i);
    if (ch == '1') {
        count++;
    }
}
```

This is assuming performance is irrelevant, of course - which in my experience it *usually* is. Your first option will almost certainly be more efficient, as the second requires converting the number to a string first. But unless you *need* that efficiency, I'd stick with whatever code is simplest to understand - and in this case, I'd suggest that's the text-based representation.

(As an example of that: how confident are you that your first example works with negative numbers? How about the same question with your second example?)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a quick benchmark:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long num = 1657345918972817181L;

        long time = System.nanoTime();
        int i1 = byString(num);
        long t1 = System.nanoTime() - time;

        time = System.nanoTime();
        int i2 = byNumber(num);
        long t2 = System.nanoTime() - time;

        System.out.println("Result: " + i1 + " Time: " + t1 + "ns");
        System.out.println("Result: " + i2 + " Time: " + t2 + "ns");
    }

    static int byNumber(long num) {
        int count = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            long digit = num % 10;
            if (digit == 1) {
                count++;
            }
            num /= 10;
        }
        return count;
    }

    static int byString(long num) {
        int count = 0;
        String s = String.valueOf(num);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch == '1') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

The result was as excepted:

```
Result: 5 Time: 18923ns
Result: 5 Time: 1924ns
```

The string representation need more time to compute. I tested this for larger and smaller numbers.
If I give a string to my methode byString(String num) I get these results:

```
Result: 5 Time: 5453ns
Result: 5 Time: 1924ns
```

It is faster, but avoiding the string method is still the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The first one assuming you have the `int` in your lap.

It's almost certainly faster because it doesn't require a memory allocation operation and involves less code.

However in light of the edit where you might read an `int` or `String` from the console the answer would be to use what's in front of you.

In most realistic systems you would want to receive the input as a string at some point if only for input validation. 
In that event dragging it into an int in order to unpack its digits back out is just unnecessary logic.

Comment: what if `String s = scanner.nextLine()` instead of maintaining a duplicate memory?

Comment: You're assuming that performance is the most important requirement here. It usually isn't, IME.

Comment: If you have those two sitting in front of you pick #1. No one in a code review should decide to replace #1 with #2. It can only hinder. I agree it might be irrelevant and you wouldn't replace #2 with #1 unless it were a bottleneck. But there should be no question that #2 is over engineered.

Comment: @UmaKanth That edit was added later. I've updated my answer. As I said that would be a matter of 'work with what's in front of you'.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is better.

To convert an integer to a string the String.valueOf function has to do the repeated divisions and modulus, that's the only possible way to convert from an integer to a base 10 string.

So the number of operations in method 1 is:

```
2N (N = length of the string)
```

while in method two it is higher, because after String.valueOf does its conversion you still have to get each individual character and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a number to a string requires similar code as yours, but a string needs additional memory and some further processing, so your **first** idea is the better one.